# Empty UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsmutablearray

I have a editable tableView and i cant remove the last object heres my method :

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView beginUpdates];
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
    {
        [self deletePermittedFriend:[friendsIDs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        [tableDataList removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }

    [tableView endUpdates];
}
```

and if the tableDataList MutableArray have only one last object gives me an error :

> *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-2380.17/UITableView.m:1070 2013-05-21
>   11:41:47.306 EzMall[3398:907] *** Terminating app due to uncaught
>   exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update:
>   invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in
>   an existing section after the update (0) must be equal to the number
>   of rows contained in that section before the update (1), plus or minus
>   the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted,
>   0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of
>   that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'

Answer (score 3):

It looks that you forgot to call this UITableView method:

```
– deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:
```

BTW: It is always good practice to read error messages.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        [tableDataList removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }


    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPath, nil] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
    }
```